# how can i Draw a line in ios map using overlayer

Tags: google-maps-api-3, ios4, ios6

I want to draw a line on ios map using overlayer. I have one code for draw a line on map. But it is not working for me. Can any one help me.

MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta=.03;
    span.longitudeDelta=.03;

```
MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.span=span;
region.center=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.046259, -76.851195);

[_myMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
[_myMapView regionThatFits:region];

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapWebView:)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleTap.delegate = self;
[self.myMapView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[singleTap release];

CLLocationCoordinate2D commuterLotCoords[5]=
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.036399,-76.872208)
};
 MKPolygon *commuterParkingPolygon=[MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:commuterLotCoords count:5];
    [_myMapView addOverlay:commuterParkingPolygon];
```

In this above code we can change the end point from this line"**CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.036399,-76.872208**)" But in always the start point is 
lat  0.000003, long 0.000000. how can i change the start pint. Could any one help me to solve this issue.